# Distribute Reflector assembly list

Tags: .net, assemblies, distribution, reflector

Does anyone know of a Reflector add-in that allows you to distribute assembly lists? That is, the lists that can be maintained when using the **File, Open List** menu option?

I have a list of assemblies for development that needs to be updated between several machines used by different developers at the moment. Something less painful would be great! I'd also prefer not to trash their existing config, just add/update a single assembly list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built one that may work for you.  You can download it at: http://jasonhaley.com/files/Reflector.AssemblyListExport.zip

It will allow you to both import and export Assembly Lists in Reflector.

Comment: Very nice!! Left feedback on your blog.

Answer (score 1):

It ends up in `Reflector.cfg` which is either in the directory you're running Reflector from, or the relevant virtual store. For example, mine is in

```
C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Reflector
```

on Vista.

Unless you need different configurations for the different VMs, I suggest you just set the config file up as you want it, and then copy it to all the VMs. (Or write a little script to fetch the One True Config File from a known place and then start Reflector, if that's easier.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I didn't mention that this would be amongst multiple developers and I'd prefer not to destroy their config. I've updated the question now.